# How to create object file of type 'Blob' in typescript/js - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, file, blob

as you can see on the object the index 1 has a File type on it while the first one has no File type  which causes Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.

How do I create an object and push it to the files where it will have a File type on it like index 1 .
Let say I have an array of object test , I want to push that object to files and it should have a File Type.

Cause index 1 come from a file upload , while index 0 is the one I have inserted but it has not of type 'Blob'., any workaround on this one?

#ts snippet code

```
  files: File[] = []
  insertNewObject() {
    if(array.length !== 0) {
      let test : File[] = array.map(item => { return { ...item, name: item.fileName }; })
      this.files = test
      console.log('this.files', this.files)
    }
  }
```

Any idea guys ? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Just a heads up that the `AngularJS` tag should be used instead of `Angular` if you're not using Angular 2 or higher

Comment: Noted Sir .....